# Need help in understanding difference between generic and non-generic object reference

Tags: java, generics

In this java code

```
public class Gen<T> {
    private Gen object;            //line 1
    public Gen(Gen object) {       //line 2
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

I could replace line 1 with `Gen<T>` and line 2 with `public Gen(Gen<T> object)` separately, thus coming up with 4 different scenarios.

What's the difference when `Gen<T>` is used instead of `Gen` in object references?

Comment: [Raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

You create the ability for the object to handle any data type.

For example you can create an object of type `Integer`:

```
Gen<Integer> generator = new Generator<>();
```

Or String:

```
Gen<String> generator = new Generator<>();
```